# if i input more than 1, i got force close

Tags: android

if i input

```
kunci = a and pesan = b my output is 8
```

but if i input

```
kunci = asd and pesan = d or kunci = a and pesan = qw
```

my application forced close

```
my error i got error "String index out of bounds" at line 77.
```

please, can somebody help me? i've try to fix it, but i didn't get any solution. please help me..
thanks ..
regards.

this's my XOREnkripsi.class

```
package com.enkripsisms;

public class XOREnkripsi {
public String charToBinary( char c ) {
    int ascii = (int)c;
    String binaryChar = Integer.toBinaryString(ascii);
    String addBit = "";

    if(binaryChar.length() < 8) {
        for( int index = 0; index < 8 - binaryChar.length(); index++ ) {
            addBit = "0" + addBit;
        }
    }
    return addBit + binaryChar;
}

public String XORKriptografi( String plain, String key ) {
    StringBuffer enkripsi = new StringBuffer();
    for( int index = 0; index < plain.length(); index++ ) {
        int panjangk = key.length();
        Character teksX = new Character(plain.charAt(index));
        Character keyX = new Character(key.charAt(index%panjangk));
        int xor = Integer.parseInt(teksX.toString()) ^ Integer.parseInt(keyX.toString());
        enkripsi.append(xor);
    }
    return enkripsi.toString();
}

public String binaryToAsciiToString( String onebit ) {
    int ascii;
    ascii = Integer.parseInt(onebit, 2);
    return Character.toString((char) ascii);
}
```

}

tulisPesan.class

```
public void sandikan ( View v ) {
    kunci = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kunci);
    pesan = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pesan);
    String k = kunci.getText().toString();
    String p = pesan.getText().toString();
    int pk = k.length();
    int pp = p.length();
    binaryText = "";
    plainChiper = "";
    String ciper;
    if( k.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Maaf, kunci harus diisi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent tulisPesan = new Intent();
        tulisPesan.setClass(this, tulisPesan.class);
        startActivity(tulisPesan);
    }else{
        String acak = "";
        double acakN;
        for (int e = 0; e<pk; e++) {
            acakN = Math.random() * 25 + 65;
            acak = acak + (char) acakN;
            k = acak;
        }
    }

    if (k.length() != p.length()) {
        for (pk = 0; pk < pp; pk++) {
            String tambahk = "";
            tambahk = tambahk + k.substring(0, 1);
            k = tambahk;
            }                       
        }

    XOREnkripsi xor = new XOREnkripsi();

    for(int a = 0; a < pk; a++) {
        binaryKey = binaryKey + xor.charToBinary(k.charAt(a)); //my line error
    }

    for(int b = 0; b < pp; b++) {
        binaryText = binaryText + xor.charToBinary(p.charAt(b));
    }

    binaryChiper = xor.XORKriptografi(binaryText, binaryKey);
    for(int d = 0; d < binaryChiper.length(); d=d+8) {
        plainChiper = plainChiper + xor.binaryToAsciiToString(binaryChiper.substring(d, d+8));
    }

    chiperAllText = chiperAllText + plainChiper;
    ciper = chiperAllText;

    Intent hasilPesan = new Intent();
    hasilPesan.setClass(this, hasilPesan.class);
    hasilPesan.putExtra("ciper", ciper);
    startActivity(hasilPesan);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the value of `pk` in the loop `for (pk = 0; pk < pp; pk++)`. This means that it will be `pp` afterwards. In fact, this loop is quite useless in its current state as it destroys the old `k`, and gives it a value of `substring(0, 1)` `pp` times. So `k` will be size 1.

Since `pp` is bigger than 1, you get an invalid index.

Comment: No problem. If you find this answer useful you can give it a thumbs up and click the tick sign to flag it as the correct answer.

Comment: how ca i do that? i really dont know. i'm sorry.

Comment: It seems the question is closed, so you cannot flag my answer as being correct. Maybe upvoting my answer by clicking the triangle above the 0, on the left of my post still works.

Comment: can you help me how can i get all contact on phone and save them on my database? i've tried but i didn't get what i mean :( i've posting too, but i didn't found the answer :( can you pllease help me?

Comment: You should open a new question for this. This way, more people can see your question and help you.